# How can I change a variable after a set amount of time once a view is displayed with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, if-statement, timer, swiftui, state

I have three states of a game: start, playing, end. I want to display a view when the game is in "start" mode and after a few seconds change the game state to "playing" and as a result change the view displayed.

This is what I have so far:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        Color(red: 0.96, green: 0.96, blue: 0.96).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        if(skateGame.getState() == .start){
            Text("Start is active").onAppear(perform: {
                skateGame.startGame()
             })
                
        }else if(skateGame.getState() == .end){
            Text("done")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some code for the skateGame class:

```
enum StateOfGame{
    case start
    case player1Set
    case player2Set
    case player1Try
    case player2Try
    case end
}

class SkateGamePlayLocal{
    
    private let player1 : Player
    private let player2 : Player
    private var stateOfGame : StateOfGame = .start
    
    init(player1: Player, player2: Player){
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
    }
    
    func startGame(){
        self.stateOfGame = .end
    }
    
    func getState() -> StateOfGame{
        return self.stateOfGame
    }
}
```

How would I go about making this work?

Comment: It's not a "video game" it's just an interface to help play a game irl. It functions just like a normal app showing different views depending on what is pressed or if some time has passed.

Comment: What is the problem? What does not work?

Comment: It never calls "skateGame.startGame()", I'm open to any solution to this, it docent have to be a change of my code.

Comment: I have also tried sleep(3) but that docent display any view until after 3 seconds.

Comment: Can you show some more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the example code is missing both timer any View "state" that the timer might update to trigger updating the UI, both of which would be essential to make it work.

For a simple example of this that does something similar to what is being asked about have a look at HwS's ["How to use a timer with SwiftUI"](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-a-timer-with-swiftui).

Moving the timer out of the view and into `SkateGamePlayLocal` or something similar will require understanding the role of `ObservableObject`, `@Published`, `@ObservedObject` and `@StateObject`. Again worth having a look at HwS's resourses on this, e.g. ["Sharing SwiftUI state with @ObservedObject"](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sharing-swiftui-state-with-observedobject)

Good luck.